# FULL OUTER JOIN gera erros

Tags: mysql, join

Estou tentando executar o seguinte script MySQL

```
SELECT 
`AccessDayClass`.`total` AS  'em aula', 
`AccessDayNotClass`.`total` AS  'em casa', 
`AccessDayClass`.`DateOnly` AS  'week' 
FROM `AccessDayNotClass` 
FULL OUTER JOIN `AccessDayClass` ON `AccessDayClass`.`DateOnly` =  `AccessDayNotClass`.`DateOnly`
```

E o servidor está respondendo com

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near **'OUTER JOIN `AccessDayClass` ON `AccessDayClass`.`DateOnly` =
>   `AccessDayNotClass'** at line 6

Eu utilizei `INNER JOIN` e funcionou corretamente, o problema só ocorre com o `FULL OUTER JOIN`. A seguir a estrutura da ambas as tabelas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uso o MySQL 5.7.19

Comment: MySQL não tem FULL JOINS, mas talvez possam ser emulados. 1) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html
2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como demonstrado [nessa resposta do SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384298/why-does-mysql-report-a-syntax-error-on-full-outer-join), o MySQL não suporta o comando `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Como explicitado na resposta supracitada, você pode emular um `FULL OUTER JOIN` utilizando o `UNION ALL` de um `LEFT JOIN` e um `RIGHT JOIN`. Assim, sua query ficaria:

```
SELECT 
 `AccessDayClass`.`total` AS  'em aula', 
 `AccessDayNotClass`.`total` AS  'em casa',
 `AccessDayClass`.`DateOnly` AS  'week' 
FROM `AccessDayClass`
LEFT JOIN `AccessDayNotClass` ON `AccessDayClass`.`DateOnly` =  `AccessDayNotClass`.`DateOnly`
UNION ALL
SELECT 
 `AccessDayClass`.`total` AS  'em aula', 
 `AccessDayNotClass`.`total` AS  'em casa',
 `AccessDayClass`.`DateOnly` AS  'week' 
FROM `AccessDayClass`
RIGHT JOIN `AccessDayNotClass` ON `AccessDayClass`.`DateOnly` =  `AccessDayNotClass`.`DateOnly`
```

Lembrando que o `UNION ALL` manterá inclusive registros que venham a ser duplicados pelo uso de `JOIN`. Caso queira eliminar duplicatas, utilize apenas `UNION`.